# Can you start a filename with a $?

Tags: php

I've never even considered this before, but one of my clients is trying to name a file starting with a $; $template.php.

Is this allowed?

I'd like to be able to give him a reason if it's no allowed?

Thanks!

Comment: You could fire up your server and try...

Comment: Yes, I did that before I posted.  I get this error: No input file specified.  I'm just trying to get the "Official" answer so I can pass it on to my client.

Comment: If it's because you're doing it with PHP and it's name is not single-quoted, it may be because it's going to get parsed as `$template` being a variable, so `.php` will be attempted.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the down vote.  I guess you can't ask "ANY" question you have on here...

Comment: I didn't downvote you, or vote to close. just so you know.

Comment: Jared, no, someone down voted the question, then didn't offer any reason to why or any help to my original question.  Just a little frustrated...

Comment: If you have an error message, you should provide the exact error message that occurs when you try to save, as well as the exact code. That's your real question, "Why can't I save a filename as `$template.php`?".

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear on my question.  The file saves properly in Dreamweaver.  The error comes in when you try to view it from a browser.  Then you get the "No input file specified" error in the browser window.

Comment: Provide your code and any errors in the question (from here and in the future). This will clear up any ambiguities. No offense, but the question itself is "naive", since the underlying filesystem is what is saving the file, not PHP. Although it appears that it's actually a double-quoted variable "problem", e.g., `"$template.php" ~ ".php"`, which is all PHP.

Answer (score 7):

That depends entirely on what filesystem you're using. You can start a filename with `$` on all of the major filesystems I know of — FAT, FAT32, NTFS, ext2, ext3, ext4, ... *(Huh. My experience of file systems is actually quite limited. Interesting.)*

Remember that if you're doing this from PHP, you need to be sure you're not using a string literal in double quotes, because within a string literal in double quotes, `$` introduces a variable. If you're using a literal `$`, either use single quotes or escape it with a backslash.

Comment: He's running a Windows IIS7 server.  Not sure the filesystem on his server though.  I guess I wanted to know if PHP allows it.

Comment: @Rick: I doubt PHP cares what characters are used in filenames. But remember that in double-quoted string literals, `$` is special -- I've added a note to the answer about that.

Comment: @Rick: If he's running Windows IIS7, I'd give it about a 99% chance it's using NTFS, and a file starting with `$` is fine. :-)